# Python - Telnet or SSH multiple devices

Tags: python-3.x, paramiko, telnetlib, parallel-ssh

I am currently using `telnetlib` and `paramiko` to connect to a server and gather some configuration from it. It took around 30 minutes to gather configuration of 50 servers. But now I need to connect around 50k servers. So by this method this is going to take a much more longer time.

I have read about `pssh` but in my case im not able to use it because some of the servers are slow to respond and im not able to connect to them. Can anyone please suggest any alternative to get this done in short span of time ?

Comment: What is the question? What problem do you have with Telnetlib or Paramiko?

Comment: The number of servers i need to connect is very high and its taking more time. So is there anyother way to achieve this in short period of time

Comment: SSH login takes time. Switching libraries/clients will unlikely get you better results. Use multiple threads.

Comment: Use parallel SSH libraries like https://github.com/ParallelSSH/parallel-ssh/ or https://github.com/Rahul-RB/ParallelizeSSH/ to simplify your task.